# Write Query to Iterating through employment data tables and performing sum of service duration

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on employees database and trying to query employees result set with service duration of each employee. Service Duration will be calculated by subtracting Employment History table Ondate with APP date and TER date. there are two tables

Table 1 - Employees

```
Id - Primary key,
Name,
post,
Office,
Salary
```

Table 2 - Employment History

```
Id - Primary Key
ActionType,
OnDate,
EmployeeId - Foreign Key
```

There are two main action types:
APP - Appointment
TER - Termination

I need to calculate the duration of the Employee history if action types are APP and TER

Table 2 - (Employment History) present data like this

```
Id | ActionType | OnDate    | EmployeeId
-----------------------------------------------
1 | APP         |02/02/2011 | 1
2 | TER         |03/05/2018 | 1
3 | APP         |01/07/2018 | 1
4 | TER         |02/06/2019 | 1
5 | APP         |01/01/2008 | 2
6 | TER         |02/03/2014 | 2
```

Currently i just joined two table with INNER JOIN. If an employee history has two job record then it will give duplicate record like this

```
EmpID | Name | OnDate    | EndDate    | Duration
----------------------------------------------
 1    |emp1  |01/01/2016 | 02/06/2017 | 1.5 year
 1    |emp1  |03/08/2017 | 31/12/2018 | 1.4 years
 2    |emp2  |02/03/2015 | 05/04/2016 | 1.1 year 
 2    |emp2  |01/05/2017 | 19/03/2019 | 1.10 years
```

Instead of this i want to get duration of each employee record and sum each individual record and show it in one row

I want the result set like this

```
Id | Name | Service Duration
----------------------------
1  |emp1  | 2.9 years
2  |emp2  | 2.2 Year
```

is it possible to get result like this. please help

Comment: what is your current query

Comment: In your query do `group by id, name` and `sum(duration)`

Comment: If you want to add the word `'year(s)'` to your value, do so in your presentation layer, not in the SQL. `'1.5 year' + '1.4 years' = '1.5 year1.4 years'` and the `SUM` of those 2 values is an error along  the lines of *Cannot perform `SUM` on `varchar`*. Also, you would have problem with sorting, as `'10.1 years'` is **less than** `'2.0 years'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select Id, sum(Duration)
from EmploymentHistory
group by Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
declare @tbl as table (Id int, ActionType nvarchar(10), OnDate datetime, EmployeeId int)

insert into @tbl values (1,'APP','02/02/2011',1)
insert into @tbl values (2,'TER','03/05/2018',1)
insert into @tbl values (3,'APP','01/07/2018',1)
insert into @tbl values (4,'TER','02/06/2019',1)
insert into @tbl values (5,'APP','01/01/2008',2)
insert into @tbl values (6,'TER','02/03/2014',2)

select EmployeeId, sum(wspan)/12.0 [Service Duration] 
from (
  select 
        a.*, datediff(month, a.OnDate, b.OnDate) wspan 
  from @tbl a join 
       @tbl b on a.id=b.id-1 where a.ActionType='APP'
 )x group by EmployeeId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `EmpId` in your query to get the sum of the `Service Duration`

```
;WITH EmploymentHistoryCTE AS
(
    SELECT eh.EmpId, 
           SUM(DATEDIFF(month, eh.OnDate, eh.EndDate) % 12) AS 'ServiceDuration'
    FROM EmploymentHistory eh
    GROUP BY eh.EmpId
)

SELECT eh.EmpId, 
       e.Name, 
       eh.ServiceDuration
FROM EmploymentHistoryCTE eh
INNER JOIN Employees e
ON e.Id = eh.EmpId
```